# Colour of the etched horizontal line different when I create dynamically then from resource. Why?

Tags: mfc

When I use the RC file with this defined in a DIALOGEX

```
// In .RC file
CONTROL         "",IDC_SEPARATOR_0,"Static",SS_ETCHEDHORZ,7,7,139,1
```

It turns out gray.  But when I do it dynamically like this:

```
CStatic separator; // in MFC dialogue class

// in OnInitDialog()
separator.Create(nullptr, WS_CHILD | SS_ETCHEDHORZ | WS_VISIBLE, rect, this, id + 1);
```

It turns out darker gray.  An example shown here:

[image]

You should see on your screen two lines.  The upper line is slightly darker than the lower line.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Did  you try to switch the position of the two lines?